# Всем привет подскажите мне как мне на телефоне работать с canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

У меня есть canvas на весь экран. Я могу там рисовать, удалять что нарисовал, сохранять и воспроизводить программой что нарисовал через назначенные клавиши. Только проблема как мне на телефоне сохранять, очищать, воспроизводить. Ведь на нем нет клавиш

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Painter</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">

<canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;">Sorry, U mad bro..</canvas>

<script>
    var
        canv   = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx    = canv.getContext('2d'),
        isMouseDown = false,
        coords = [];
    canv.width = window.innerWidth;
    canv.height = window.innerHeight;

    // Code
    ctx.font = '20px Georgina';
    ctx.fillText('Если хотите очистить всё то нажмите на клафишу C .',40 ,40);
    ctx.fillText('Если хотите сохранить рисунок в временное хранилище нажмите на клавишу S ',40, 58);
    ctx.fillText('Если хотите что бы машина повторила ваш рисунок точь-в-точь нажмите на клавишу R ', 40, 75);
    ctx.fillText('* Машина не сможет повторить рисунок если вы его не сохраните в хранилище!', 40, 90);


    canv.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
        isMouseDown = true;
    });
    canv.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
        isMouseDown = true;
    });

    canv.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
        isMouseDown = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
        coords.push('mouseup');
    });
    canv.addEventListener('touchend', function(){
        isMouseDown = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
        coords.push('mouseup');
    });

    ctx.lineWidth = 10 * 2;
    canv.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e){
        if( isMouseDown )
        {
            coords.push([e.clientX, e.clientY]);
            ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        }
    });
    canv.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e){
        if( isMouseDown )
        {
            coords.push([e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY]);
            ctx.lineTo(e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY);
        }
    });

    function save (){
        localStorage.setItem('coords', JSON.stringify(coords));
    }

    function clear (){
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';

        ctx.font = '20px Georgina';
        ctx.fillText('Если хотите очистить всё то нажмите на клафишу C .',40 ,40);
        ctx.fillText('Если хотите сохранить рисунок в временное хранилище нажмите на клавишу S ',40, 58);
        ctx.fillText('Если хотите что бы машина повторила ваш рисунок точь-в-точь нажмите на клавишу R ', 40, 75);
        ctx.fillText('* Машина не сможет повторить рисунок если вы его не сохраните в хранилище!', 40, 90);
    }

    function replay (){
        var
            timer = setInterval(function (){
                if( !coords.length )
                {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    return;
                }

                var
                    crd = coords.shift(),
                    e = {
                        clientX: crd["0"],
                        clientY: crd["1"]
                    };

                ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
                ctx.stroke();

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                ctx.fill();

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
            }, 15);
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){

        if( e.keyCode == 83)
        {
            // save
            save();
            console.log('Saved');
        }
        if( e.keyCode == 82)
        {
            // replay
            console.log('Replaying...');

            coords = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coords'));

            clear();
            replay();
        }
        if( e.keyCode == 67)
        {
            // clear
            clear();
            console.log('Cleared');
        }

    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно подключить клавиши через USB-OTG кабель

Comment: Я имел ввиду что каждый среднестатистический  пользователь смартфона смог полноценно пользоваться программой. Просто не знаю какие события навесить @andreymal

Comment: Что у Вас не получается?